# what will happen if i didnt assign a variable to a function that returns a value

Tags: java, syntax

Let us consider the code

```
int function(){
    return 1;
}
main(){
    function();
}
```

I am not assigning any variable for the function call which returns an integer.It was not throwing an error. What is actually happening internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is returned on the stack, and the stack is popped, and the value is discarded. This is **entirely normal**, happens all the time. We frequently call functions that return things that we don't need to use, and so don't use.

Answer (score 0):

> What is actually happening internally?

The return value is simply discarded.

Normally if you do

```
x = foo();
```

There is code in the calling function just after the function call that is executed when it returns that moves the return value into the variable `x`. This code is simply omitted if you do

```
foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your method returns an integer value, but you are not assigning it to any variable to store it. It will print the value, if you put it.

```
System.out.println(function());
```